# May I save Mongo documents in the same loop I finding them in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

May I save Mongo documents simultaneously with finding them in PyMongo?

Like below:

```
for result in result_collection.find():

    # modify result

    result_collection.save(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [find_one_and_update](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) is your sulution.

Find a document and update it, returning the original:

```
collection.find_one_and_update({ name: 'test' }, { "$set": { name: 'test1' }})
```

Find a document and update it, returning the updated document:

```
from pymongo import ReturnDocument
collection.find_one_and_update({ name: 'test' }, { "$set": { name: 'test1' }}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```